# Echo how many users is online in last 5 minutes

Tags: php, mysql

So, I am wondering how can I get number of last online users from mysql database?
In MySQL '`lastonline`' is `2015-07-12 12:00:13am`
So I need to get number of users where is `lastonline` under `2015-07-12 12:05:00am`
I tried:

```
$currenttime = date("Y-m-d h:i:sa");
    $resulttt = mysql_query("select lastonline from users where lastonline <= '$currenttime'");
$users = mysql_num_rows($resulttt);
echo "$users";
```

I got 0, but when I change from '`<=`' to '`=>`' I got 40 (number of all my users)
How is possible to calculate number of online users under 5 minutes?
Thanks for help, really appreciated.

Also tried: `SELECT lastonline FROM users WHERE lastonline > now() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE`
Just got number of all users

Comment: `SELECT lastonline FROM users WHERE lastonline > now() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE`

Comment: Hey, Thanks for comment, it says 40 but it should not be 40, there was only 1 user online in last 5 mins

Comment: If you use the query I just gave you, it'll select the rows where time is between now and 5 minutes ago

Comment: make sure `lastonline` is a datetime column and not a varchar

Comment: I used: `$resulttt = mysql_query("SELECT lastonline FROM users WHERE lastonline > now() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE");` I just got output "40", doesnt matter if I change minutes from 5 to 60...

Comment: Like @FuzzyTree said. Are you sure it's a datetime column? Also you do realise you're only selecting the datetime column?

Comment: @FuzzyTree hey, It is datetime column

Comment: I'm afraid we can't help you any further without a look at your code or database. Something else must be causing the issue as the query is fine.

Comment: hmmm... I dont have any special things what should make this buggy, anyway, doest it matter if thats in am or pm format? I am trying to get 24hour format but I always got 12hrs format...

Comment: Also, when I change to `SELECT lastonline FROM users WHERE lastonline < now() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE` (from ">" to "<") I got 0 output, now lastonline format is 2015-07-12 00:23:48 (It was 2015-07-12 12:23:48am) Does it change things?

Comment: I have no idea what you're doing but datetime NEVER has am/pm. Please provide your schema and some sample data. http://sqlfiddle.com/ is good for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do it would be using MySQL only. This query allows you to select all rows between now and 5 minutes ago:
`SELECT lastonline FROM users WHERE lastonline > now() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE`
or
`SELECT lastonline FROM users WHERE lastonline > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)`

However, it's possible to use PHP instead. The code would be as follows:

```
$5_minutes_ago = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",mktime(date("H"),(date("i")-5),date("s"),date("m"),date("d"),date("Y")));
$resulttt = mysql_query("SELECT lastonline FROM users WHERE lastonline > ". $5_minutes_ago) or die(mysql_error());
$users = mysql_num_rows($resulttt);
echo $users;
```

On a last note: `mysql_*` is officialy deprecated. I strongly suggest updating your code to [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). The added benefit is that you'll be able to use Prepared Statements, which will protect you against SQL injection.

Comment: You can also do `$5_minutes_ago = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-5 min'));` (to keep with his format)

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '08:55:26' at line 1